# How to fix the bad WPF TextBox performance?

Tags: wpf, textbox, lag

We timed *only* how long *setting the Text in a WPF TextBox* takes by displaying the time it took if it was above 1 millisecond. Then we ran the exact same code using a Winforms TextBox.
The WPF TextBox randomly generated delays/lags of 2-11ms on one computer setup and even up to 200ms (often 50-60ms and sometimes around 200 ms) on another computer - whereas the Winforms TextBox didnt generate a single lag above 1 ms. *Please remark:* The first delay of around 7-8ms is just created once upon instantiation of the control - this one *does not matter* - just the following ones, which are created continously when you move your mouse around on the window do matter. The first delay also *sometimes* occurs with the WinForms control, but it isn't costly after instantiation.

**Used Code for the WPF-Test:**

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="TextBoxTest.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBoxTest"
  Width="800" Height="800"
  mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <TextBox x:Name="tb"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code behind**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    this.MouseMove += UpdateTextBox;
}

private void UpdateTextBox(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var rnd = MainWindow.r.Next(20);

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
    {
        _time.Restart();
        tb.Text = rnd + "";
        _time.Stop();
        if (_time.ElapsedMilliseconds > 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(_time.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
'TextBoxTest.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.10\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. 
7ms
3ms
3ms
4ms
3ms
...
```

**Used Code for the Winforms-Test:**

Everthing was the same but we replaced the TextBox in the XAML.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="TextBoxTest.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBoxTest"
  Width="800" Height="800"
  mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <WindowsFormsHost Height="40" Width="80">
            <wf:TextBox x:Name="tb" />
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Output**

```
'TextBoxTest.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.10\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'.
```

There were no delays at all.
It's obvious that it must be the WPF TextBox itself producing this lag.
We don't know whether it is a bug or intended/expected behavior.
Can you fix this lag somehow? And why does it occur?

Comment: Why is 7ms significant to you? It's a very short period of time.

Comment: If you read again, I mentioned the first delay (7-8ms) is not significant - it's the instantiation time, but the latter delays are 3ms which happen quite often and I also said on the other computer these delays went up to 50 and even 200ms

Comment: In our other project, updating textboxes which show the coordinates of the cursor-position, sometimes created visible lags when updating the UI

Comment: Why are these textboxes? Rather than textblock.

Comment: Well cause it's not actually the mousecursor but some control that the user can move - doing that implies either using the mouse(cursor) or entering coordinates for it's position manually